# Apache camel memory issue with dynamic SFTP uri for file processing

Tags: java, apache-camel, out-of-memory, buffer, jsch

Our application has been throwing **OutOfMemory** for quite sometime. At first we thought it is due to inefficient usage of collections but on deeper analysing the application and heapdump, it looks like **Apache camel** is causing this **memory issue**. We are pulling files from SFTP daily and decrypt them before going through data processing and inserting into **DB**. It looks like **Apache camel** is not freeing up the memory from its jsch buffer.

Our camel is simple, sharing a sample here:

```
from("sftpUrl"+dynamic_fileName+".pgp"+"&noop=true&delay=5m&stepwise=false").routeId("id").process(isNotAllprocessed).unmarshal().pgp(somekey,user,pwd).unmarshal().string().process(writeToDBProcessor).log("Done");
```

we tried using `streamcaching()` and refactoring the processor, nothing resolved this issue.

Other solutions for apache camel in stack overflow seems to be with **JMS**, I do not find anything related to my issue so posting this. If you know an existing answer kindly comment here.

Have any of you faced this issue?

Can someone suggest what we can do here?

**Please give an explanation why this is happening? how to avoid this?**

Comment: I tried a lot of things to get this fixed, but in the end I wrote the FTP functionality in a bean and memory usage went down by 200MB.

Comment: Yes I agree but Apache camel should able to handle this by itself. We are planning to switch with spring integration SFTP still I feel like this should be addressed. I must apologize for late reply